# Error 413 payload too large when upload image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http-status-code-413

I'm trying to upload an image from local by using **base64** to do image detection.
And everything works fine in localhost and postman.
But after deploying, I got CROS error.

I've already got cors middleware in  `server.js`

```
const express = require("express");    
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10000kb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "10000kb", extended: true }));
```

The cors middleware works fine when fetching image with url,
But when I tried to **upload image from local** by using **base64**, the console shows:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here's the solution I've tried:

1. cors-anywhere

```
App.js

    const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    
    fetch(proxyUrl + API_CALL.IMAGE_URL, {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            inputLink: inputLink,
            inputMethod: inputMethod
          }),
          credentials: 'include'
        })
```

It then shows `413 payload too large`.

Since there's no error when testing in localhost and postman, I found out some articles said it might still be the cors error.

2. CORS preflight

server.js

```
    const corsOptions = {
        origin: 'https://front-end-url/',
        methods: 'GET, POST, PUT',
        credentials: true,
        allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
        exposedHeaders: 'Content-Range,X-Content- Range'
    };
    app.options('/imageUrl', cors(corsOptions));
```

It shows error:

```
CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' 
when the request's credentials mode is 'include'
```

3. After I remove `credentials: 'include'`, it shows `413 payload too large` again.

I'm so confused... Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't happen on localhost at all?

Comment: @PayamBeirami It works fine on local host and postman, no error.

Comment: The 413 error is the actual problem. That’s what’s causing the browser to log the CORS message — not the other way around. You don’t have a CORS problem. You have 413 problem. If you fix the cause of the 413 problem, you’re likely gonna find that your existing CORS configuration is already working as expected.

Comment: First, you need to identify who is answering the 413 error. It could be your express server, or it could be something else. For example a nginx proxy that redirects requests to your express server. If this were the case, you should check if these have any setting like buffer sizes and such

Comment: Hello @sideshowbarker , I changed the bodyParser limit to 100000000kb, and also changed the limit in json.js & text.js in node_modules > body-parser > lib folder, but it still shows 413 error. I'm deploying on heroku. Is the error not about bodyParser, but about heroku?

Comment: Hello @Gerard , I changed the bodyParser limit to 100000000kb, and also changed the limit in json.js & text.js in node_modules > body-parser > lib folder, but it still shows 413 error. I'm deploying on heroku. Is the error not about bodyParser, but about heroku?

Comment: About upload size, I’m not aware of any limits that Heroku imposes.

Comment: Thank you guys! I find out the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally fix the error by placing 
`express.json()` **AFTER** `bodyParser`.

like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
```

If runing express.json() first, express would set the global limit to 1mb.

For the next person that needs more detail:
[Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large)
And for the person who needs to set Nginx config file:
[Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/18951706#18951706)

Comment: Im sure my error is coming from here and I am on ELB too. My server throws a CORS error when my post request body content length is over 1 MB! Still cant fix it.

Answer (score 6):

In express use

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))
```

But then in Nginx you also have to edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add the following line inside `http` block:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Then restart Nginx with `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: From where we can find that file on ElasticBeanstalk `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf `

Comment: I have no idea what `ElasticBeanstalk` means, but to search words inside files in Unix use grep: `grep ElasticBeanstalk /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: this was the answer for me, changing the limit in nginx did the trick, struggling with this for hours

Answer (score 0):

```
This solution is for ANDROID
```

> In my case **@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")** is used extra which is not needed.

@Multipart

> ```
> @POST("user-management/user/profile")
> @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
> fun updateProfileImage( @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,@Header("Authorization") authKey: String): Call<ProfileImageResponse>
> ```

I have removed header @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
As multipart I am using so not to use above header.

After removal of that Header code executed successfully.

> ```
> @Multipart
> @POST("user-management/user/profile")
> fun updateProfileImage( @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,@Header("Authorization") authKey: String):Call<ProfileImageResponse>
> ```